# Tentando ler o segundo Char mas não consigo - C

Tags: c, validação, char

Bom estou fazendo uma atividade que eu quero printar o seguinte:

Se inputar 1: return "one";

Se inputar 2: return "two";

Se inputar 453: return "five hundred fifty three";

E assim por diante, entre 1 e 1000.

Enfim, eu fiz do 1-9 utilizando um array chamado onedigit[]. Porém, quando tento ler o segundo (cujo tem os numeros de 10 a 19), ele está lendo três numeros abaixo sempre.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;

char* onedigit[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
char* twodigits[] = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};



int main(){

    do{

        printf("\ninsert number 1 to 1000: \n");
        scanf("\n%d", &n);

            if(n<=0 || n>1000){
                printf("\ninvalid number\n"); //numbers below 1 or over 1000 aren't allowed
            }else{

                if(n > 0 || n <= 9){

                    printf("%s\n", onedigit[n - 1]);

                }else if(n >= 10 || n <= 19){
                    printf("%s\n", twodigits[n - 10]);
                }

            }

        }while(n<=0 || n>1000);
}
```

[image: Aqui funcionando normal com um numero entre 1-9]

[image: Neste aqui eu digito 12, mas nada acontece. Quando digito numeros maiores que 12, ele retorna 3 números abaixo]

[image: Exemplo de número inputado acima de 12]

Espero ter sido claro, agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Na realidade, ele não está lendo 3 números abaixo. Como `15` é maior que 0, o bloco do ` if(n > 0 || n <= 9){` é executado. Então, o programa manda imprimir a 15ª posição do array `onedigit` na seguinte linha `printf("%s\n", onedigit[n - 1]);`. Como `onedigit` não reservou quinze posições, o programa está lendo o que quer que esteja armazenado neste lugar, no seu caso específico, o que está armazenado é o segundo elemento do array `twodigits[]`, mas poderia ser qualquer coisa. Sugestão, mude a condição `n > 0 || n <= 9` para `n > 0 && n <= 9` e use a mesma lógica para as demais condições.

Comment: E outra sugestão: aprenda a usar as ferramentas de DEBUG do seu IDE. Com um breakpoint é fácil ver como o seu código está rodando.

Answer (score -1):

você pode usar uma matriz para os vários tipo de números por extenso , as unidades , dezenas , centenas , unidade de milhar, dezena de milhar , centena de milhar , e milhões , mas seu código até vinte poderia ser assim  :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char onedigit[][10]  = { "Zero"    , "one"     , "two"    , "three"   , "four"  , 
                         "five"    , "six"     , "seven"  , "eight"   , "nine" };
char twodigits[][10] = { "ten"     , "eleven"  , "twelve" , "thirteen"          , 
                         "fourteen", "fifteen" , "sixteen", "seventeen"         , 
                         "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty"                      };
int main() 
{
int n=0;
char num[15];
do 
{
    printf("\ninsert number 0 to 1000: \n");
    /// scanf("\n%d", &n);
    fgets(num , 10, stdin);
    num[strlen(num) - 1] = '\0';
    n = atoi(num);
    if (n < 0 || n > 1000) 
    {
        printf("\ninvalid number\n"); //numbers below 1 or over 1000 aren't allowed
    }
    else 
    {
        if (n >= 0 && n < 10 ) 
        {
            printf("%s\n", onedigit[ n ]);
        }
        else 
        {
            if (n >= 10 && n < 20 )
            {
                printf("%s\n", twodigits[n - 10]);
            }
        }
    }
} while (n >= 0 && n <= 1000);
return 0;
}
```